# CakePHP 3 app broken after "composer update"

Tags: php, cakephp, composer-php, cakephp-3.0

I decided to run "composer update" command another time to get the app back up to date but now it's completely broken as it can't find a certain class anymore.

`Fatal error: Class 'App\Application' not found in /home/rlvpr/public_html/webroot/index.php on line 33`

All files in the vendor folder have been properly uploaded, so yes also all the composer autoload class mappings ...

I really have no clue what I should do now :/

Anyone got any suggestions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Try running `composer dumpautoload`.

If that doesn't work, check your composer.json for the autoload section:

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "src/"
    }
}
```

Then dump autoload again. Of course, tweak the source folder path to suit where your namespace folder is!

Comment: Thanks. I did that but I noticed this deleted a bunch of cakephp plugins I had in cakephp-plugins.php :/ Very strange.

My autoload section seems ok I presume
````"autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "src"
        }
    }````

Comment: add a / on the end of src and try it again, like my example

Comment: Yes, I did try that but no help unfortunately.

Comment: I have the impression it's got something to do with "read permissions" on the new NAS we installed" ...
If I want to require a single package I get this: "composer.json is not readable" (though I can just open that file through the console)

And everytime I do "composer update" it wants to install all packages instead of updating the ones it should update. So perhaps I can't read the composer.lock also? :/

Comment: if you type `ls -la /path/to/site`, what are the owner and group set to?

Comment: -rw-r--r-- 1 Laurent 197610   2749 May 23 15:36 composer.json

I don't know what it means ;-)

Comment: It means the owner has read and write access, the group has read access, and everyone else has read access. The owner seems to be 'Laurent'.

Comment: So that means I'm the owner of that file, though when I want to install a new package through "composer require" it says composer.json is not readable for some reason... 

I did copy all cakephp files from the NAS to my local drive and then the whole problem from my initial question above does work... So clearly a permission issue which I think can't generate the autodump correctly.

So would've to figure out this permission thing.

Nevertheless thanks for all the help :)

Comment: How is he NAS connected? Do you mount it somewhere? And how? I have a NAS, and it runs it's own linux. Maybe the same users and groups aren't in it?

Answer (score 0):

Run:

```
composer dump-autoload
```

See also [dump-autoload](https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#dump-autoload)